# Make UI Bootstrap accordion heading fully clickable area

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a UI Bootstrap accordion whose heading I want to be fully clickable, not just the title like the default behavior.

```
<accordion class="fda-accordion panel-group panel-group-square" close-others="oneAtATime">
    <accordion-group is-open="fdaClass1Open" ng-show="fdaRecallsClass1Count">
            <accordion-heading>
                <div class="panel-heading-blue">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw" ng-class="{'fa-minus': fdaClass1Open, 'fa-plus': !fdaClass1Open}" style="margin-right:10px"></i>
                    FDA Class 1 Recalls ({{fdaRecallsClass1Count}})
                </div>
            </accordion-heading>            
        {{fdaRecallsClass1Content}}
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

Is there some workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the anchor that's handling the toggle is wrapped around the header text rather than the `div`. I would style the content of the heading with negative margins and matching positive paddings corresponding to the padding values of the heading `panel` in order to expand the clickable area beyond the `div`.

So say for instance the padding on your `panel-heading` is `9px 15px`, you'd have the following css in your `panel-heading-blue` class

```
.panel-heading-blue{
    margin: -9px -15px; 
    padding: 9px 15px;
}
```

Comment: You can put it inline on that same `div` element if you'd like